# How to connect a heroku app to a wix domain?

Tags: heroku, dns, velo

I bought a year plan with a free domain on wix.com for my portfolio. Now I've coded my portfolio and deployed on heroku. How can I disconnected my original wix-made portfolio page with the domain and connect the domain with my heroku app?

I've tried add domain and also edited my DNS Record on wix's domain dashboard (advanced tab).

> screen shot of the wix dashboard: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17LzbD-DKn-QMH9adFdZVrtjE72gB_dvh/view?usp=sharing

To be specific, I only changed the CNAME's 'points to' section to the 'DNS Target'([something].herokudns.com) provided by heroku. (I've also tried to put [appname].herokuapp.com in the field)

> screen shot of the heroku setting:
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gwxxe9VpO8zpSHNE1lfWPs0VJk4HB-fi/view?usp=sharing

Finally, I hope I can see my new self-coded portfolio when I visit the domain I got from wix.

Answer (score 1):

As per your screenshot there is A record in ns which needs to be removed. I think you are pointing via cname which can be considered as an alternate option but would recommend you to add a addon on heroku name pointDNS and copy all the records from wix.com to pointDNS.Please try to follow below mentioned steps

```
1. Add the domain to your heroku app => heroku domains:add domainname

2. Go to resources-> add `PointDNS` addon,
    a.Verify by clicking on pointDNS
    b.Copy all NS records from wix to pointDNS
    c.Update NS issued by pointDNS (dns8.pointhq.com,dns12.pointhq.com) in wix
```